# Convert Dekad to start and end date in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe containing a column with Dekad (10-day) information e.g. Dekad 1 is Jan 1 to jan 10th, Dekad 2 is Jan 11th to jan 20th and so on.

Is there a way to get start and end day information given the dekad number? I can do this by hardcoding but a more pythonic solution would be better.

The dataframe looks like so, and i want to add a new column called date_range_dekad that contains the start and end date concatenated into a string

```
                  CEI  Dekad
0         160.004352     1
1           0.000000     2
2           0.000000     3
3           0.000000     4
4           0.000000     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option using an [`interval_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.interval_range.html) :

```
dekad = 10

rng = pd.interval_range(
    pd.Timestamp("20230101"), pd.Timestamp("20231231"), freq=f"{dekad-1}D")
    
df["date_range_dekad"] = [
    "{:%d-%b} to>> {:%d-%b}".format(
        *(rng[dk].left, rng[dk].right) if dk == 0 # to be adjusted ?
        else (rng[dk].left  + pd.Timedelta(days=dk),
              rng[dk].right + pd.Timedelta(days=dk)))
    for dk in df["Dekad"].sub(1)
]
```

Or, by slicing a [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) :

```
rng = pd.date_range("20230101", "20231231", freq="1D")

df["date_range_dekad"] = [
    "{:%d-%b} to>> {:%d-%b}".format(
        rng[dekad*dk:dekad*(dk+1)].min(),
        rng[dekad*dk:dekad*(dk+1)].max())
    for dk in df["Dekad"].sub(1)   
]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

          CEI  Dekad    date_range_dekad
0  160.004352      1  01-Jan to>> 10-Jan
1    0.000000      2  11-Jan to>> 20-Jan
2    0.000000      3  21-Jan to>> 30-Jan
3    0.000000      4  31-Jan to>> 09-Feb
4    0.000000      5  10-Feb to>> 19-Feb
```